# How do I remove duplicate contacts from Google+?

Tags: contacts, google-plus

I have a problem with my contacts in conjunction with google+.
Like most, I had already a lot of people in my contactlist, which is synced with the contacts in google mail. With google-plus, I have added a lot of people to circles. Those people from Google+ are now all individual entries in my contacts, but only on the phone.

After deletion I recognized, that all people are also removed from my circles.

So how to add people to circles, without having them appear as duplicate contacts?

**EDIT:**
Thanks anyone, yes, some of you are right - it seems that those people are put in an extra list "Other contacts" (also visible in the web interface). You have to uncheck this group in the settings > displaysettings. Can someone of those people put this in an answer, so I can accept it, thanks :)

Comment: The same problems happens with Google Talk. I hope that Google fixes that soon.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. None of the people I have added to google+ have been added to my phones contact list. Is there anything I should do to trigger it? (HD2, Android 2.3.7, CyanogenMod 7)

Comment: @bendemes they are put in to "All Other Contacts" group, and I think by default in CM7, that group is not displayed.

Comment: Are you _sure_ they're not in your Google Contacts on the web? Did you look under "Other Contacts"? It's my experience that adding someone to a G+ Circle adds them to "Other Contacts" and has resulted in some duplication for me. If you're displaying "Other Contacts" on your phone that would account for what you're seeing (since those contacts are mostly hidden from you in the web app).

Comment: @RyanConrad Oh yes I see the all other contacts option if I tick it I do then see all my Google+ contacts in my contacts list creating dupes. I might have missed something but why don't you just hide all other contacts? Or only show those with phone numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you Circle someone in Google+, it also adds them in the "Other Contacts" in Google Contacts.

Simply de-select "Other Contacts" in the Contacts app to remove these contacts from your view.

When multiple show up (in Google's New Contact vies), deselect the person's old contact info from ANY circle. That way Google doesn't "hang on" to them, they get integrated into your existing contact for that person.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is to *join* contacts:

1. Select the duplicate contact
2. Edit the contact
3. Access the menu for the *edit contact* page, and select the *Join* action.  You can then select the contact you want to merge with.

Comment: This is also a nice solution, so I did a upvote. But I follow people (and G+ pages) on G+ that don't belong in my contactlist, this is no perfect match for me.