# How can I group duplicate contacts from different sources (Google, WhatsApp, etc)?

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-plus, whatsapp-messenger

I have installed an ICS ROM (Virtuous Inquisition 4.0) on my phone. In my address book I am syncronizing all contacts from my Gmail, Google+ and WhatsApp accounts with the consequence that some contacts have THREE entries! Is the ICS address book not able to group them together by default? I know this question is similar: [How do I remove duplicate contacts from Google+?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15213/duplicate-contacts-with-google), but the proposed solutions don't seem to work or are not really adequate.

Comment: I guess these steps can reproduce the problem:  (1) Create a contact "A" with phone number, no email on google contact; (2) Let B add you to his/her circle on google+; (3) Change contact A's email address to B's email. .... You now see two contact are merged on web, but seperated on phone.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

- Select the duplicate contact Edit the contact
- Access the menu for the edit contact page, and select the Join action
- Select the contact you want to merge with from the suggested list, or search for
  the appropriate one.

Doing this will link the contacts.